# How to get information by bar code?

Tags: android, barcode

I'm a new android developer, and I try to create an app for using bar code. I try ZXing, it is very easy. But now I need get information about product by bar code. How can I do that?

Comment: nice question, voting up, as m also new to that..

Comment: You would have to use some sort of product lookup.  I know google shopping has some facility for searching UPC, but there is a number of other services out there.

Comment: It's unclear if you're asking 1) how to capture an image containing a barcode and extract a product number from the barcode, 2) use a barcode number to lookup product info, or 3) all of the above.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use some kind of web service to look up the product information associated with an UPC/EAN code using for example an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). A quick Google search turned up the [Internet UPC Database](http://www.upcdatabase.com/).

Here's a sample record of what data they provide: http://www.upcdatabase.com/item/0081697521221

Please carefully read their ToS: http://www.upcdatabase.com/docs/terms.asp

Answer (score 1):

To use one dimensional barcodes use PRODUCT_MODE. 
If you want to be able to scan them all don't set anything in extras scan_mode.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
//intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bar code gives you nothing but a number (product number). You need to have a web service where you can send this number to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the barcode reader by intent, then the user scans the barcode(if they have the barcode reader installed), and the barcode reader sends the data to your app

here's the code on how to do it.
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

as you can see in `public void onActivityResult`

these are the data returned by the scanner

```
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
```

Answer (score 0):

Year 2023  solution: Use Built In Android Bar code scanner api:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-code-scanner:16.0.0'
}

GmsBarcodeScanner scanner = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this);
scanner
    .startScan()
    .addOnSuccessListener(
        barcode -> {
          // Task completed successfully
        })
    .addOnCanceledListener(
        () -> {
          // Task canceled
        })
    .addOnFailureListener(
        e -> {
          // Task failed with an exception
        });
```

Source:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner?hl=de#java